# グーグルマップAPIのNearby_Searchで、指定した範囲内の賃貸物件だけを返すようにしたい。

Tags: python, api, google-maps

PythonでGoogleMapAPIを動かし、地図中の一定範囲内の賃貸物件を検索したいのです。

指示内容としては、例えば広島駅周辺なら

```
self.gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=APIkey)
result = self.gmaps.places_nearby((34.396872, 132.487693),radius,type='',keyword='')
```

このような形のコードを書いているのですが、区役所、病院やレストラン、ホテルなどが引っかかってしまいます。
検索結果を絞るために `keyword='アパート'` などと入力すると今度は結果が全く返ってきません。賃貸物件だけを抽出することができないまでも、もう少し絞り込む方法はないものでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

使用しているライブラリは
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/blob/master/googlemaps/places.py
でしょうか？

ソースの説明によると、keywordは検索に使用される言葉のようです。ただし"アパート"と設定するとGoogleが検索しに行った際に"アパート"の言葉が登録されていないと検索されないようです。（物件名が"○○アパート"なら検索されると思います）
そもそもplaces_nearbyのメソッドはショップの検索などには有効そうですが、賃貸物件の検索には向かなそうです。

別の方法としてはplaces_nearbyのメソッドが持つ別のパラメータ（nameなど）を使用して検索できる方法を検討するか、または完全に別のメソッドを使用することを検討したほうが良いかもしれません。（適切な他のメソッドが存在するのかわかりませんが）

Comment: 実験しましたが、例えば
`result = gmaps.places_nearby((34.396872, 132.487693),radius=500,type='',keyword='アパート')`
で結果が返却されますがradiusは指定していますか？

Comment: ご検討ありがとうございます。使用しているライブラリはそのURLのものです。radiusは700で指定しており昨日までは結果が返ってこなかったのですが、先ほど自分でも試して見たところ、結果が返却されてきました。質問投稿以前に色々いじってしまったので不具合が再現できなくなっているので、一旦解決ということにしたいと思います。回答ありがとうございました。